# store a result in variable just like Java in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, types

I have this code.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM users", (error:mysql.MysqlError, results:any) => 
{
    if (error)
        throw error;
    else
    {
       console.log(results);
    }
});
```

**Is this possible**

```
var result = connection.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

and then we retrieve data from the result (just like in java ResultSet)

Comment: you can use await and async of ES6 to acheive this.

Comment: Your results object contains all data which are fetch by query. No need to use var result = connection.query("SELECt * FROM users");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s better to use asynchronous functions whenever possible for nodejs developers but you can use another library like `sync-mysql` to achieve what you want :

```
const result = connection.query("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Another option is to use `await` in ES6 like this (remember that not all version of nodejs support ES6 await, you can check your version compatibility here : https://node.green ):

```
const result = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```